# py-spy Error: Failed to get process executable name. Check that the process is running

Tags: python

I was trying to run performance test by using command line: `py-spy top -- python main.py`, but got the following error:

> Error: Failed to get process executable name. Check that the process is running.
> Reason: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (os error 31)
> Reason: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (os error 31)

The py-spy version i was using ispy_spy-0.3.14-py2. Python version is 310, and OS is Win 10.

How can i know what device affected this python performance test? How to fix this error?